# Creating a list of random numbers with weights and restrictions

Tags: python

I'd like to create a list of 3 numbers with statistical weights attached.
I have found the random.choices function which does that amicably.

```
random.choices(population=[0,1,2], weights = [0.4,0.3,0.3], k=100)
```

But in addition to that I'd like to apply some restrictions on this random number generation where I'd like to

- forbid 0's from occurring consecutively
- forbid 2's from occuring more than two times in a row

random.choices() does not have this functionality it seems.
Does anybody have a suggestion on how to approach this?

Kind regards and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since the samples output by `random.choices` (remember: with replacement) are statistically independet, just throw out those members that violate your restrictions. Here is an example generator:

```py
def restricted_choices(population, weights=None, k=1, restrictions={}):
    """Yield k values from `population` with restrictions.
    Works almost like `random.choices()`.

    For every item (k, v) in `restrictions` holds:
      the yielded sequence does not include a sub-sequence `v * [k]`.
    """
    N = 0 # count how many values we have yielded so far
    last_value = None # last value that was yielded
    repeat_count = 0 # how often it has been yielded in a row
    while N < k:
        while True:
            x = random.choices(population, weights)[0]
            if x == last_value and 1 + repeat_count == restrictions.get(x, 0):
                continue
            break
        yield x
        N += 1
        if x == last_value:
            repeat_count += 1
        else:
            repeat_count = 1
            last_value = x
```

Use it like this:

```py
list(restricted_choices(population=[0,1,2], weights = [0.4,0.3,0.3],
                        k=100, restrictions={0:2, 2:3}))
```

Note however, that the resulting sequence will not be `[.4, .3, .3]`-distributed any more.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer H. Doebler! Works like a charm. I was hoping to figure out myself how to rewrite this function in a dynamic way, so that it can handle different amounts and types restrictions without needing to be rewritten. I'm currently at this point:

Comment: `def nchoices_with_restrictions(probability_splits,restrictions):
    choice_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < 100:
        while True:
            x = rd.choices(range(len(probability_splits)), weights = probability_splits)[0]
            for restriction in restrictions:
                if x == restriction:
                    continue
                choice_list.append(x)
                i += 1
                break
    return choice_list
`

Comment: Which is not only formatted horribly but also simply doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know what type of restrictions you think of. Anyway, to implement restrictions looking an arbitrary number of elements backwards, I would suggest to use a `collections.deque` as a flexible replacement for `last1`, `last2` and in order to 'encode' your restrictions, you could use something like `forbidden={0: [[0]], 2: [[2,2]]}` for the example in the question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer1 The restrictions would be of the same type, as in they would all restrict a number from occurring certain times. So instead of 0 being not allowed to occur consecutively, a 1 wouldn't be allowed to occur 8 times in a row.    There also could be several more restrictions being imposed. In my example there were only two rules in place but the desired function should be able to handle a theoretically infinite amount of rules. (In practice more than 5 probably won't be necessary)

Comment: @Difio I updated my answer accordingly. You can now hand over `population`, `weights`, and `k` just as `random.choices` as well as a dictionary `restrictions` that encodes which element of `population` is forbidden to occur how often in a row.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot. I haven't gotten around to implement this but you have helped me tremendously!